# How do I take the live stream coming from a settop box on to a Rpi and then send it to TV?

Tags: input, output, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3, television

In general, output goes directly from a settop box to the TV, I am trying to break it in between. I wish to pass the output of settop box to Rpi, Do some some basic processing and then send the output to TV.

I've searched multiple sources but still not sure if this can be done the way I want it. There are links regarding how to take input from camcorder, etc and also links on how to send the output of Rpi to a monitor.

But none of them have a way to take output from a settop box and give input to a TV directly.

It would would be great if someone could help me with the same. Preferably a detailed process, else some  that would point me in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This is more of a hardware problem than a software problem. Raspberry Pi doesn't have this capability natively. You're looking for a video capture card.

Comment: If i attach a video capture card will that be sufficient?

Comment: Of course, there would be at least some configuration involved. However, I don't think there is a video capture device available for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9205/creating-an-hdmi-pass-through-connection

Comment: checked that out but not sure how helpful it was. Could you explain a little more elaborately?